# PayPal Checkout page design

Tags: paypal

I have implemented PayPal for my site, and i used IPN checkout. Currently when I press PayNow button on my site it shows PayPal Checkout page with following design http://c2n.me/iM28i8

But there is another PayPal Checkout page design (see http://c2n.me/iMwGZk), than the one I use. How can i switch to that design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second screen shot is new layout design that will be offered going forward . Currently it is not rolled out everywhere , so your buyers can see the different checkout page depending on the various factors like their country , ip adrees etc . This is only the change in design and  will not affect the way PayPal process the transaction .

And there is no way to control the checkout design , it will be decided by the PayPal .

Answer (score 0):

The second screenshot looks a lot like the payment page paypal has for mobile devices. are you sure that's not the mobile one?

Comment: Hmmm... the thing is that second picture was provided by my customer, for whom i implemented PayPal. I pretty much sure it was not a mobile device (please see full screenshot  [link](http://c2n.me/iNaeld)), but i will double check with him now. As i see from link on the screenshot it is Express checkout, so maybe it is not possible to set view for this page for IPN. I searched everywhere and already asked PayPal support about this but all they offered me is to create sandbox account |(