# New vs old PayPal checkout pages, still random selected?

Tags: paypal

First of all, I know that this issue has been raised a few times on Stack Overflow the past couple of years. The problem is that sometimes I get the new PayPal checkout pages and sometimes I get the old pages.

I've made two test accounts in my sandbox. The first one got the new design, and the second got the old design. My live account seems to be using the old design. It may seem that US accounts get the new design, and foreign accounts get the old design, but I'm not sure about this.

See for example these questions from 2014

- [PayPal Checkout page design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480687/paypal-checkout-page-design)
- [Paypal Express checkout showing old site instead of new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675770/paypal-express-checkout-showing-old-site-instead-of-new)

The answer earlier has been that the new design is slowly being rolled out, and that it is randomly selected.

Now, my question is if anyone knows if this is still the case, and if/when we will be able to select the new design?

Comment: Did you get any further with this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's based off of whether or not you're already logged into a PayPal account.

When ever I was logged into my merchant account, I would always get logged out and redirected to the old site. However if I was logged into my personal account, I was shown the the "new" design and asked to login first too.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case here at least. I have verified that I am not logged in to any account before initiating the purchase, and it always follows the different merchant accounts.

Conversely, if I stay logged in as a test purchaser but change the merchant credentials from one account to the other, it changes layout from one payment to the next.